# vue-i18n,'TypeError: _vm.$t is not a function'

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n, vue-server-renderer

I'm using Vue 2.6.14 and vue-i18n 6.1.3 I can't figure it out how to put i18n translation in error.

When I first entered the page is normal,but there is an error after refresh

```
TypeError: _vm.$t is not a function
```

in entry-client.ts

```
import { ClientOptions } from '@fmfe/genesis-core';
import { createClientApp } from '@fmfe/genesis-app';
import i18n from './langurage';
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './app.vue';

export default async (clientOptions: ClientOptions): Promise<Vue> => {

    return createClientApp({
        App,
        clientOptions,
        vueOptions: {
            i18n
        }
    });
};
```

Because I don't know much about the system architecture, so I don't know how to go to mount i18n

Comment: We don't know what is `genesis-app` or `genesis-core` and how it works. Perhaps you should consult their manual? Otherwise look at the Vue-i18n manual - they have good examples.

Comment: vue-genesis ,Lightweight Vue SSR library ,has Micro frontend and Microservices